# Valid expressions to the quote function

Tags: r

According to the manual of `quote(expr)`:

> expr: any syntactically valid R expression

While `quote(x==y)` returns a call `x==y` successfully, `quote(x=y)` fails:

```
Error in quote(x = y) : supplied argument name 'x' does not match 'expr'
```

Both `x=y` and `x==y` are syntactically valid R expressions, aren't they? Why `quote()` fails on `x=y`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As it says in `?"="`:

> The operator ‘<-’ can be used anywhere, whereas the operator ‘=’ is
>   only allowed at the top level (e.g., in the complete expression typed
>   at the command prompt) or as one of the subexpressions in a braced
>   list of expressions.

Using `=` in an argument to `quote` is not using it at the top level, so you have to put it in braces or parentheses, but you still have to be careful how you evaluate this expression, since the rules above will still apply.

```
quote({x=y})
quote((x=y))
```

To address a comment:

As Gavin Simpson said: basically, the "top level" is when you type or run the code at the prompt and is not within a function call.  Take `z = quote(expr=x)` for example.  `z = quote(...)` is evaluated at the top level, but `expr=x` is not because it's inside a function call.

In `quote(expr=x)`, `=` is being used to assign the value of `x` to the function argument `expr`; so you're no longer working at the top-level, you're constructing a function argument list (pairlist).  The reason `quote(x=y)` fails is because `quote` doesn't have an `x` argument.

The top level context is described briefly in [R Internals](http://cran.wustl.edu/doc/manuals/R-ints.html), in [Section 1.4, Contexts](http://cran.wustl.edu/doc/manuals/R-ints.html#Contexts).

Comment: If you consider it as "a great answer" shouldn't you accept it?

Comment: @Jilber: Exactly! I am waiting it!

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich: So what's the difference of "topness" level of "=" sign, between quote(x=y) and quote(expr=x)? Would you describe it in your answer?

Comment: Ohh sorry, I hadn't seen that detail

Comment: @AliSharifi -- `expr` is the single formal argument of `quote()`, so in that one case, the role played by `=` is that of argument matching (rather than assignment to a symbol). Make sense?

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Yes it makes sense, but still I have not a good sense of *topness* as stated in the answer

Comment: @AliSharifi By "top level" it essentially means the situation where you type or run the code at the prompt and is not within a function call. So `> x = 1` is top level, but `> x = foo(x = 1)` is *not* the top level for the `x = 1` bit as that is interpreted as passing argument `x` value `1`. The `x = foo(....)` part is however top level.